# Can not load external spreadsheet in flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, stylesheet

I imported two projects in Flex Builder 3 (A and B). Those two projects A and B are in the same folder and in mxml file which is located in A/src  I have

```
<mx:Style source="../../B/b/assets/b.css" />
```

this relative path is correct, but Flex Builder keeps showing message:
"Problem finding external stylesheet: ../../B/b/assets/b.css"

What am I doing wrong? Btw, I am newbie in flex, so, please, don't be harsh. :)

Thanks in advance,
D

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I believe a project cannot access assets outside its `src` folder.

Comment: I also have this issue. I am compiling old code (which I know used to work) from the command line using ant and flex-4.6. As I said, I know it used to work (slightly old version of Flex SDK). But figure it could possibly be enviromental...

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago. For which platform do you use flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the better approaches is you could make a flex library project to hold your shared assests, then link to the shared project via Project Proprties -> Flex Build Path -> Library Paths -> Add Project.  Then you can include the stylesheet.

Note that all paths like this link relative to the src folder.  If your stylesheet is in folder src/assets/css, then the source attr should be 'assets/css/my.css'

another way would be to add another source path folder to your project via same eclipse menu path as above to Flex Build Path, but on the first tab (can't remember name!)